# Reinforcement learning converges for mean loss but not for each training data

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

Here I show a dummy example that represents my actual problem.

My neural network (NN) receives one input and gives the probabilities for two output nodes. The code for the NN is:

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, N, M):
      super(Net, self).__init__()
      self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(N, 4)
      self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(4, 4)
      self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(4, M)
  def forward(self, x):
      x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
      x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
      x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x),0)
      return x
```

The ABM class is our model that iteratiely sends calls to `Net::forward`, and based on the probabilities, chooses an action if it's the first index, increments `agent_count`. Inputs `xx` are stored in `states` which will be used to `backward`.

```
class ABM:
    def __init__(self,_nn,_t_data):
        self.nn = nn
        self.iteration_n = _t_data.iteration_n
        self.target_value = _t_data.target_value

    def run(self):
        for jj in range(self.iteration_n):
            xx = self.generate_input();
            self.states.append(xx); # store inputs
            ys = nn.forward(xx);
            action = self.draw(ys);
            if (action == 0):
                self.agent_count+=1

        loss = self.calculateReward();
        return loss;

    def generate_input(self):
        return torch.ones((1),requires_grad = True)
    --some other attributes--
```

When the run is over, `error` is calculated as `error = (target_value - agent_count)/target_value` which is a value between -1 and 1.
In order to train the model, the `error` is applied to the probability of the first output node of NN. This is to correct the NN in a way that predicts the right probability for the first output. The code is:

```
class ABM:
    def calculateReward(self):
        error = (self.target_value - self.agent_count)/self.target_value
        reward = torch.tensor((-error), requires_grad = True)
        #since all states are same, we just choose the first one
        state = self.states[0]
        ys = nn.forward(state)
        actionProb = ys[0]
        action_reward = actionProb * reward            
        return action_reward;
    --some other members--
```

Two parameters of `iteration_n` and `target_value` used in the ABM are defined in the training data class as:

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self,tt , tv):
        self.iteration_n = tt
        self.target_value = tv 
    target_value =0;
    iteration_n=0;
```

The harmony between different parts of the code is done as:

```
#### start optimization ####
nn = Net(1,2)
optimizer = optim.Adam(nn.parameters(), lr=0.01)
# create training data values
training_items = []
training_items.append(Train(1000,800))
training_items.append(Train(500,200))
error_record = []
for ii in range(100):
    print("############ start iteration #%d ################"%ii)
    for t_item in training_items:
        model = ABM(nn,t_item)
        loss = model.run()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step() 
        error_record.append(loss.item())
```

Now let's present the problem.
If I only define one training item as `Train(/*iteration number*/1000,/*target value*/800));`, the NN is optimized as expected:

[image: convergence graph for single training data]

however, by defining two training items, although the average error declines to zero, the error on each training data stays high:

[image: convergence graph for two training data]

Is there any idea how to solve this issue?

I have omitted some parts of the code here to make it more readable. The full running code is available on [minimal ABM](https://github.com/janursa/minimal_ABM/blob/master/python.py)